# How to print .afp file in eclipse to a printer?

Tags: java, eclipse, afp

I had worked on converting file format to .afb file using FOP service.
(Code smaple below)

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException;
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;

public class FopService 
{

public FopService() throws FOPException, TransformerException, IOException
{
    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();  
    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("E/myfile.X")));
    try{
    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_FOP_IF, out);
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); // identity transformer
    Source src = new StreamSource(new File("E/ResultAFP.afp"));
    Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
    transformer.transform(src, res);
  }
  finally {
      //Clean-up
    out.close();
  }
  }
}
```

Now i need to print this .afp file on a printer.Any java api for it??  Explain the steps.

Comment: You won't be able to print AFPDS files directly.
It's not a page description language that printers handle natively (as opposition to lower level ones like PS or IPDS).

Comment: I am talking about Advanced Function Presentation(apf format files).

Comment: Me too. AFPDS = Advanced function printing data stream (ie. .afp printable files)

Comment: I did not say it cannot be printed (it is in fact its main purpose : to be printed). It is a high level page description language that has to be converted to some lower level one (usually IPDS for AFP) by a RIP software. BTW : It happens to be a format I know quite well, i wrote parsers and generators for it.Your best try,in an office setup, is to try and automate an afp viewer program to print your file

Comment: Can you elaborate in detail how to print afp file ?can it be done in java too?

Comment: Hi oualid-jabnoune, can you help me in converting afp to pdf.